# For loop explanation

Tags: c#, for-loop

So I have been trying to figure out how it works, but my book isn't explaining it well enough.

Can someone explain me why the result is 45? Isn't it supposed to be 55?

Here is my code & the results are in the images below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int loopStart;
        int loopEnd;
        int answer = 0;

        loopStart = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        loopEnd = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        //The code will keep running as long as End is bigger than start
        for (int i = loopStart; i < loopEnd; i++)
        {
            answer = answer + i;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: the debugger is *perfect* for sorting out this sort of thing

Comment: well, someone who's just learning what a `for` loop is probably hasn't reached the debugger chapter yet! :)

Comment: Please try to provide minimal example that demonstrates the problem. In this case loop with hardcoded values would be much better than complete WinForms program with reading values from controls.

Comment: Don't misuse tags. This is not a question about Visual Studio; and since you are writing in C#, don't tag with Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just iterate through your loop like this**:

```
loopStart = 1
loopEnd = 10
answer = 0

1<10 - 1
2<10 - 3
3<10 - 6
4<10 - 10
5<10 - 15
6<10 - 21
7<10 - 28
8<10 - 36
9<10 - 45
10<10 = false - You've declared that 10 have to be SMALLER than 10
```

**How to fix it:**

```
i <= loopEnd
```

**Then it looks like this:**

```
loopStart = 1
loopEnd = 10
answer = 0

1<=10 - 1
2<=10 - 3
3<=10 - 6
4<=10 - 10
5<=10 - 15
6<=10 - 21
7<=10 - 28
8<=10 - 36
9<=10 - 45
10<=10 = 55 - Yup it is SMALLER OR EQUAL than 10.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code executes between 1 and 9 (inclusive). The sum of all these numbers is 45.

To get the loop to go to 10 (which is what you seem to have intended), the conditional needs to return true if `i` is 10, thus:

```
for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
{
    answer = answer + i;
}
```

Note `<=` which is "Less than or equal to" as opposed to "strictly less than".

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminates at `i < loopEnd`, so it never executes its block with i = 10.

1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45

Answer (score 0):

if you  want the answer you are expecting you have to say i <= loopEnd instead of < ...